# How can I call function in view in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a function in xamarin and I want to use the value of this return function as a column in my view. So here is my function:

```
public int setColumn()
        {
            int column = 0;
            int product_number = 0;
            foreach (Product product in AllProducts)
            {
                product_number++;
                if(product_number % 3 == 0)
                {
                    column++;
                    product_number = 0;
                }
            }
            return column;
        }
```

So this function apparently set the column number for my view. So I want to show 3 columns in one row and I am counting via looping my list. So here is my view:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Grid.Column="setColumn"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                BackgroundColor="#EEF2FF"
                                Command="{Binding AddProductCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            />
                        </Grid>
```

So here I want to call my function -->  **Grid.Column="setColumn"** and set the column number.

Comment: either call your method from a property and bind the XAML value to this property, or just do the assignment in code instead of XAML

Comment: What is its specific execution logic, and what execution sequence should it be in?